# Footsteps with Unity Wwise too fast

Tags: unity, wwise

Hi I'm trying to implement my footsteps for a game using Wwise but they are way too fast and I can't change the speed. I made a random container with different footstep sounds, then added the script. However ! it is playing the footsteps really fast in succession. I tried adding wwise silence between the footsteps in a sequence container, but that didn't change anything. I need the footsteps to be random, but i want to be able to control the time between each footstep.

The game is in first persone so i can't put it on an animation. How do I do it?

Comment: What script did you add? How are you indicating to it when to play a footstep sound?

Comment: if(direction != Vector3.zero) {bruitDePas.Post(gameObject);} i ended up doing something different to play the event from time to time  if (direction != Vector3.zero)
        {
            nbrPas++;
            if (nbrPas > vitessePasSon)
            {
                //lancer event bruit de pas
                bruitDePas.Post(gameObject);
                nbrPas = 0;
            }
        }

Comment: If that solved your problem, post it as an Answer below. If you still need help, edit your question to show the code and explain what help you need with it.